# Does the WMI event Win32_VolumeChangeEvent work on Windows XP

Tags: wmi, usb

I'm trying to use the following c# code to detect the attached/removed event of
usb mass storage devices. I'm using the Win32_VolumeChangeEvent.

```
  
// Initialize an event watcher and subscribe to events that match this query            
var _watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher("select * from Win32_VolumeChangeEvent");
_watcher.EventArrived += OnDeviceChanged;
_watcher.Start();
```

```
void OnDeviceChanged(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(args.NewEvent.GetText(TextFormat.Mof));
}
```

The problem is that this works fine on Vista but it doesn't work on XP at all (no events received). The Microsoft documentation says that this should work (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394516(VS.85).aspx). I googled for this quite a while and found other that have this problem too. But I also found a couple of articles which claim that this kind of query (mostly in vbscript) works with XP. But I cannot find some offical information from microsoft for this issue and I can't believe that Microsoft have overlooked this issue for three service packs.

So my question is: has anybody used the Win32_VolumeChangeEvent with success on XP or can provide a link/explanation why it shouldn't work on XP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in your own [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394516%28VS.85%29.aspx), the Minimum Supported Client version for `Win32_VolumeChangeEvent` is Windows Vista. Anyway, as suggested [here](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/registered-event-detect-usb-insertion-85299.aspx), you can execute a query within interval in the `root\\CIMV2` scope. Here an example from a code of mine:

```cs
WqlEventQuery query;
ManagementScope scope;
ManagementEventWatcher watcher;
public void DoWork()
{
    // Check if OS Version is earlier than Windows Vista
    if (USBHandlerWorker.OSVersion() <= 6)
    {
        scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
        scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;

        query = new WqlEventQuery();
        query.EventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent";
        query.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        query.Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'";

        watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);
        watcher.EventArrived += watcher_EventArrived;
        watcher.Start();  
    }
    else
    {
        watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
        // The event types 2 and 3 are for plug and unplug events
        query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent " +
            "WHERE EventType = 2 OR EventType = 3");
        watcher.EventArrived += watcher_EventArrived;
        watcher.Query = query;
        watcher.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I asked this question six years ago it was not written in the documentation, but now it is. Anyway, I hope nobody is still developing for Windows XP ;-)

Answer (score 0):

"Win32_VolumeChangeEvent .. is found only on Windows Server 2003" - [source](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/feb06/hey0213.mspx)